# Change new button order and default content type using pnpPowerhsell

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, modern-experience, sitepages

For the Library 'Site Pages' on communication Site, I need to change the order of the content type and set some of them to hide.

`SetDefaultContentTypeToList`  for default content type for List 'Site Pages'

The issue was well known to see here : [set default](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/1107)

so the proposed by the community is here: but doesn't hide content type in new button ,

```
 $doclib = Get-PnPList -Identity "<name of your doclib>" -Includes ContentTypes, RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder
$rootFolder = $doclib.RootFolder
$contentTypeToHide = Get-PnPContentType -List $doclib -Identity "<name of the ct to hide>";
$list = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeId]'
foreach ($i in $rootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder) {
    if($i.StringValue -ne $contentTypeToHide.StringId)
    {
        $list.Add($i)
    }
}
$rootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = $list
$rootFolder.Update()
$doclib.Update()
Execute-PnPQuery
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the PowerShell below.

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com"
$ctx = Get-PnPContext
$web = Get-PnPWeb
$doclib = Get-PnPList -Identity "<DOCLIBNAME>" -Includes ContentTypes,RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder
$rootFolder = $doclib.RootFolder
$ct = $doclib.ContentTypes | where {$_.Name -eq "<CT TO BE HIDDEN>"}
$ct2 = $doclib.ContentTypes | where {$_.Name -eq "<CT TO BE HIDDEN, USUALLY FOLDER>"}

if($rootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder -eq $null)
{
    $contentTypesInPlace = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeId]'
    #$contentTypesInPlace = $doclib.ContentTypes | where {$_.Id -ne $ct.Id}
    foreach($ct in $doclib.ContentTypes | where {$_.Id -ne $ct.Id -and $_.Id -ne $ct2.Id})
    {
        $contentTypesInPlace.Add($ct.Id)
    }
}
else 
{            
     $contentTypesInPlace = [System.Collections.ArrayList] $rootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder
     $contentTypesInPlace = $contentTypesInPlace | where {$_.StringValue -ne $ct.Id}
}

#Set the UniqueContentTypeOrder to the collection we made above
$rootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeId]] $contentTypesInPlace

#Update the root folder
$rootFolder.Update()                
Execute-PnPQuery
```

Refer to: [SharePoint Online: Hide content type on list](https://blog.jussipalo.com/2017/12/sharepoint-online-hide-content-type-on.html)

Comment: Execute-PnPQuery
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-PnPQuery], ServerException

Comment: thank you , this solution works for others libraries but not for 'site Pages" , so i do it with csomPowershell